# How to select a object field for map value in Scala using groupby

Tags: scala

Here is a newbie scala question. I have a list of people with Person objects with `getName()` and `getYearOfBirth()` methods. I am using groupBy to group the Person objects but I only wish to put the 
names into the map as Person will have lots of additional fields in future. The years will be the keys.

```
val people = List(
Person("Tom", 1985),
Person("Abigail", 1987),    
Person("Joyce", 1984),
Person("James", 1987),
Person("Scott", 1985),  
Person("Ruth", 1984)
)


var birthdayMap = people.groupBy(x=> x.getYearOfBirth()) // map to getName() ?
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
scala> persons groupBy (_.year) mapValues (_ map (_.name))
res9: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]] = Map(1984 -> Set(Joyce, Ruth), 1987 -> Set(James, Abigail), 1985 -> Set(Tom, Scott))
```

Comment: Perfect, vielen Dank. I am using scalaj-collection to return the Map as java.util.Map. However the key value is scala.collection.mutable.Buffer. How do I access the individual names in this Buffer from Java?

Comment: @Reimeus I don't quite understand your question. But if you access it from Java may I hint you at `collection.JavaConversions.bufferAsJavaList`.

Comment: Thanks, Ive decided it is cleaner to do all collection iteration in my Scala helper objects rather than pass then out to the Java layer.

Answer (score 0):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, most collections are provided with the [groupMap](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#groupMap[K,B](key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,CC[B]]) method which is an equivalent of a `groupBy` followed by `mapValues`:

```
people.groupMap(_.yearOfBirth)(_.name)
// Map[Int,List[String]] = Map(1985 -> List(Tom, Scott), 1984 -> List(Joyce, Ruth), 1987 -> List(Abigail, James))
// equivalent to people.groupBy(_.yearOfBirth).mapValues(_.map(_.name))
```

given:

```
case class Person(name: String, yearOfBirth: Int)
val people = List(Person("Tom", 1985), Person("Abigail", 1987), Person("Joyce", 1984), Person("James", 1987), Person("Scott", 1985), Person("Ruth", 1984))
```