# How to select a object field for map value in Groovy using groupby

Tags: groovy

I have a list of people with Person objects with getName() and getYearOfBirth() methods. I am using groupBy to group the Person objects. I am using groupBy to group the Person objects but I only wish to put the names into the map as Person will have lots of additional fields in future. The years will be the keys.

```
    class Person {
        String name
        int yearOfBirth
    }       

    def people = [ 
        new Person(name:"Tom", yearOfBirth:1985),
        new Person(name:"Abigail", yearOfBirth:1987),
        new Person(name:"Joyce", yearOfBirth:1984),
        new Person(name:"James", yearOfBirth:1987),
        new Person(name:"Scott", yearOfBirth:1985),
        new Person(name:"Ruth", yearOfBirth:1984)
    ]           

    //people.groupBy(_.year) mapValues (_ map (_.name))  how to map here?
```

This is a direct port of a [Scala app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541838/how-to-select-a-object-field-for-map-value-in-scala-using-groupby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be:

```
def nameInYear = people.groupBy { it.yearOfBirth }
                       .collectEntries { [ (it.key):it.value.name ] }
assert nameInYear[ 1984 ] == [ 'Joyce', 'Ruth' ]
```

So, group them by their year of birth to get a YEAR->ListOfPeople map
Then, for each of these groupings, collect a map of YEAR->ListOfNames

Answer (score 0):

Another, more imperative, solution would be:

```
def namesByYear = [:].withDefault { [] } 
people.each { namesByYear[it.yearOfBirth] << it.name }

assert namesByYear[1985] == ['Tom', 'Scott']
```

The same thing can be transformed into one expression using [`inject`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#inject%28U,%20groovy.lang.Closure%29), though i think becomes less readable:

```
def namesByYear = people.inject([:].withDefault { [] }) { map, p ->
    map[p.yearOfBirth] << p.name
    map
}
```